# c3.js Changing min/max values changes boundaries

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have dynamic min and max values for axis y

```
  calculateMin() {
    let min = _.minBy(this.props.chartData, function(o) { return o.value; })['value'];
    return this.props.chartData.length <= 1 ? min - 5 : min;
  }

  calculateMax() {
    let max = _.maxBy(this.props.chartData, function(o) { return o.value; })['value'];
    return this.props.chartData.length <= 1 ? max + 5 : max;

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.ref.current.chart.axis.range({min: {y: this.calculateMin()}, max: {y: this.calculateMax()}});
```

But after changing time range I am always getting smth like that:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**What Am I doing wrong and how to fix it?**

P.S Here is my chart's axis config:

```
 axis={{
            x: {
              type: 'timeseries',
              tick: {
                format: x => {
                  return (
                    x.getDate() + ' ' + MONTHS_FOR_CHARTS[x.getUTCMonth()]
                  );
                },
                padding: 0,
                extent: [2, 3],
                count: 4,
              },
            },
            y: {
              // padding: 0,
              inner: true,
              tick: {
                format: data => data + '%',
              },
            },
```